# vue with nginx issue

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, vue.js

Hi I am running node+express+vue

Here is my nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name mydomain.me;
  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /root/mydomain.me.cert;
  ssl_certificate_key  /root/mydomain.me.key;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

With the above configuration I can access my site using https://mydomain.me but in Chrome's console there are some error appears.

```
GET https://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1517580112789 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
client?d420:175 [WDS] Disconnected!
sockjs.js?3600:1601 GET https://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1517580112789 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Would you please help me why localhost:8080 is still appears? and how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

The websocket is trying to directly connect to 8080 through nginx. You need to proxy that connection,as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change WebSocket URL when you initialise your connection:

```
var sock = new SockJS('https://mydomain.me');
```

Comment: Where I need to mention this var sock

Comment: @UmarDraz you don't use websockets in your application?